# Repeated measures to predict binary outcome

Tags: logistic, repeated-measures, prediction, binary-data

I would like to predict outcome of an event based on repeated measures. The problem is the following one:

I have 100 patients with measures of a certain feature at different times, but all the patients do not have the same number of measures.

[image]

The test data has been taken before knowing the outcome and the aim of this work is to predict outcome based on this measures.

I have tried with MATLAB using fitrm which fits the data to a repeated measures model, but my problem is how to define the within subject-factors for not constant number of measures for each patient.

How can I do this?